# Executing same Python program with different arguments in parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i execute the same python program in parallel (I am thinking of x10) with the only difference being two input arguments representing a time-range?  I need it for some data-processing, which otherwise will take too long to finish

I know i can do it manually in shell by starting 10 scripts one by one, but it does not seem to be the most "elegant" solution + I would also love to define arguments for each of those programs dynamically in the "main" python program.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @Merlin IO. It has multiple select and insert statements from/into the database which are executed in each cycle of a loop of about 1 500 000 cycles

Comment: @Merlin All the selects are happening from table A and all the inserts are into table B.

Comment: .@Dennis can you write the code in SQL. Dont go of out-of-process to the database.

Comment: @Merlin  I understand that it is better to keep it all in SQL (inside the database). Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out how to do that yet.

Comment: .@Dennis...can you delete this question, it a SQL problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enclose your script in a main method, like so:

```
def main(args):
    a, b = args
    # do something


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_arguments()
    main(args)
```

Then you can use a second script together with `multiprocessing.Pool`, to run the main method with different arguments.

```
from myscript import main
from multiprocessing import Pool



a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(4) as pool: # four parallel jobs
        results = pool.map(main, zip(a, b))
```

Comment: Thanks Max, looks clean and simple. Will try it out in a minute

Comment: How come you specified 5 pairs of arguments but there are only 4 parallel jobs to run? Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: The pool has a number of 4 parrallel tasks. So only 4 jobs can be run simultaniously. So what will happen is, that the first 4 jobs are executed and as soon as the first one has finished, the fifth is started. If you have more than 4 cores, you can pass a higher number to `Pool`

Comment: Ah, Got it :) Thank you :)

Comment: Hi! I have similar problem, except that my main function takes 11 arguments. I have three such sets of 11 arguments that I wish to pass to into main function and then launch it in different cores. I wrote my script but it is throwing error saying that I am passing one argument instead of 11.

Comment: @MaxNoe would mind checking (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68305077/how-to-run-a-script-in-parallel-for-different-datasets?noredirect=1#comment120719470_68305077). I am trying to apply the idea you gave but I am not sure how I can pass different datasets

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following in shell:

```
python main.py [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] &
python main.py [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```